# How can I get a list of Virtual Directories in WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Is there a programmatic way to get a list of all the defined virtual directories in my current application?

I'm trying to find a way to avoid hard-coding the output of some processes in another location besides the weblogic.xml file.

Comment: There used to be a JMX for this, but seems to be deprecated in WLS 10+ which version are you on?